# How to select a schematic of the coordinate vs energy representing a rearrangement reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reaction-coordinate

Here's the question

[image]

[image]

For a reaction to take place the net energy should go down, and thus option (d) can be discarded.

We are now left with options (a), (b), and (c).

A $3^{\circ}$ carbocation is more stable than a $2^{\circ}$ carbocation, therefore the 3rd dip in the graph should be lower than the 2nd dip as more stable means lower energy.

Thus now we are left with options (b) and (c).

How do you decide between (b) and (c)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **(b)**.  The initial step of the reaction should take energy.  Otherwise the reactant molecule itself is unstable.  The very initial portion of the curve in (c) is downward-sloped, which doesn't make sense.  If the reacting alkene could relax to a different conformation without any activation barrier, then it would do so.  But the fact that the reactant is a stable, isolable molecule with a well-defined chemical structure indicates that no such barrier-less relaxation is possible.

Thus, **(b)** is a better answer than (c).

Comment: no, the answer is c

Comment: Not according to me it isn't.

Comment: well, the answer key could be wrong, but your answer doesnt really convince me much

Comment: Feel free to downvote.

Comment: I would agree with you on the initial downward bit, which makes 0 sense. However, (b) also doesn't make sense to me, with a carbocation intermediate that is more stable than the starting alkene. Even (c) says that the tertiary carbocation is lower energy than the alkene. I would prefer to believe that carbocations are high-energy intermediates, and that if you added, say, perchloric acid to the double bond, and let the system reach equilibrium, you would not obtain a salt of the carbocation with perchlorate counteranion, because that is what is implied. I don't like any of these answers.

Comment: One might like to think that because a carbocation is tertiary, it is really stable because of all the wonderful hyperconjugation. That neglects the fact that it is still a carbocation, featuring positively charged, octet-deficient carbon, which is inherently more unstable than any neutral molecule from which it is derived. What do you think the pKb of an alkene is? I don't think it's anywhere near significant.

Comment: Well with the data in place that the alkene is more stable than the carbocation, it is quiet evident that the answer is c and not b. As alkene is more stable than carbocation thus there is a deeper dip initially than later on. As the carbocation is less stable than the alkene the dip isn't as great as the dip around the alkene.

Comment: As Curt said and as I said c doesn't make sense either. You are basically choosing the least bad answer, and between b and c, which answer is least bad is really quite subjective. I would argue for this. http://i.stack.imgur.com/SbKkb.png

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is c. As the carbocation would have higher energy than the alkene. Which is the case in (c) but not in (b). In (b) it can be seen clearly that carbocation is at a lesser energy than alkene which certainly isn't true!